# Support Vector Machine image Classifier in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svm, libsvm

I am developing a image classifier using SVM. Just for development and debugging reasons I am using 16 images at the moment 8 each of 2 different classes. The problem in my program is that when I determine which class the object belong to it gives me always one class only. For example my labels for 16 images are {-1 and 1}. I always get 1 even when I predict my training data with that of label -1.

My algorithm:
I am using bag of word model to create dictionary with 1000 clusters in each.
For feature extraction I use SURF.

```
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF");
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create("SURF");

int cluster_size = 1000;

BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(cluster_size, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 0.001), 1, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS);
BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(extractor, matcher);
```

Next I read the images from the training set... (I skip the reading code here..) but for each image that the program reads:

```
detector->detect(image, keypoints);
extractor->compute(image, keypoints, descriptors);
bowTrainer.add(descriptors);
```

is done to create the dictionary.

The training data path and labels are read from the text file and as I stated above i use -1 and 1 as labels since i just have 2 classes.

Now I will talk about my SVM part:

```
SVMParams param = SVMParams () ;
param . svm_type = SVM :: C_SVC ;
param . kernel_type = SVM :: LINEAR ;
param . degree = 10; 
param . gamma = 20; 
param . coef0 = 0; 
param . C = 7;
param . nu = 0.5; 
param . p = 0.5; 
param . class_weights = NULL ; // for CV_SVM_C_SVC
param . term_crit . type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER  ;
param . term_crit . max_iter = 100;
param . term_crit . epsilon = 1e-6;
```

Note some params I have twicked just to see if I get any closer to response but it not help. The initial parameters were extracted from the libsvm library and I changed it to see it I get any results. But it didn't help.

Finally I train and than predict.
    SVM svm;
    svm.train(train__,labels, Mat(), Mat(), param);

Now again my problem is that I dont get the right results. To be extact if I test data from class of -1, the svm predict gives 1 and for 1 it gives 1 as well. Can someone explain to me what is the step I have missed that is stopping my program from getting the correct response.

Thank you and sorry for long question.

Comment: How do you compute the `train__` training vector which you are training the SVM with? Similarly, how do you get the test vector to classify? Have you looked at these vectors to check if they make sense?

Comment: Could you show a little more code, specifically where you create the labels Mats to pass to svm.train() and svm.predict().

Comment: You might want to try [`train_auto()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-train-auto) method, it does some parameter optimisation.

Also, check if the values of class You are reading are not changed when passed to training method. Maybe Your responses mat is of `CV_16U` [type](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat%20type#mat-depth) or sth like that...

Comment: Hello friends; I am sorry to trouble you all, I was debugging the code, and a very small error was the problem. My error was simply I calculated the keypoints for test data, but by mistake i was using the keypoints of training data and therefore, the training data keypoints matched eachother since it was same and hence gave the output of the training set labels. I corrected it and now it works fine.

Comment: Also morynicz thanks for the information on train_Auto it helped me achieve good true positive results.

Comment: @rish I am doing the same task and getting the same error , can you help me in it /?

Comment: @rish how much time did it take to train 16 images?